# How to find a recursive formula for the number of combinations of {1, ...., 9} of length n, such that there are no uneven digits next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recursion

I can't figure out how to formulate this in a single expression as the number of options for each additional digit depends on the previous last digit's value, but each previous step represents the number of combinations, not a specific number.

Also, I would like to know the correct way to compute this directly, and not recursively.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe f(number of even digits taken,number of odd digits taken,is last digit even) will do? Clearly $f(1,0,1)=1,f(0,1,0)=1,f(1,0,0)=0,f(1,0,1)=1$ then recursion

Comment: Direct approach can be based on [principle of inclusion and exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) as we have only $5$ odd numbers and $5$ has only $7$ partitions into integer sums, but it's a long way to go.)

Comment: Please clarify: Can digits be repeated, as in $2343$, or can each digit appear at most once, as @Alexey has assumed?

Comment: @DanielMathias I'm sorry, all combinations of the digits, including repetitive combinations, count.

Answer (score 0):

So I'd like to implement my comment as an answer.
Let f(number of even digits taken,number of odd digits taken,is last digit even) be the recursive function with initial conditions $f(1,0,1)=4$,$f(0,1,0)=5$,$f(1,0,0)=0$,$f(0,1,1)=0$.
Now, for $m>0,n>0$ we get
$f(m,n,1)=\left(f(m-1,n,1)+f(m-1,n,0)\right)\cdot(4-(m-1))$,
$f(m,n,0)=f(m,n-1,1)\cdot(5-(n-1))$.
And $g(x)=\sum\limits_{m+n=x\\0\le m\le4\\0\le n\le5} (f(m,n,1)+f(m,n,0))$ will give the desired result.
As we have only $6$ values for $m$ and only $5$ values for $n$, the $f$ table will consist of $6\cdot 5\cdot 2=60$ values, not too much to do by hand.
If done right, the table will be similar to this:

```
               f(m,n,1)           |           f(m,n,0)           
       m=0   m=1   m=2   m=3   m=4|   m=0   m=1   m=2   m=3   m=4
n=0      1     4    12    24    24|     1     0     0     0     0
n=1      0    20   120   360   480|     5    20    60   120   120
n=2      0     0   240  1440  2880|     0    80   480  1440  1920
n=3      0     0     0  1440  5760|     0     0   720  4320  8640
n=4      0     0     0     0  2880|     0     0     0  2880 11520
n=5      0     0     0     0     0|     0     0     0     0  2880
```

([source code](https://tio.run/##hVXbjuI4EH3PV1jaoNjE0AkLaIQ2La32aaTVvswjoFY6dsA9iRPZTjfs7Hx7b9nOBXpGmgiR8qlyXU5V7PZqzo38/VOr3t9Z9g2nNKEp2a0phjdNyG5DHQZS4rG0lxyWegmw9HvAeIlKPL@QXYDgybXmyiBzbTm@kCwzXVtxp/mtVUIaAN1KlOiChETMb7OP4qZTgOwvR4fxVy41bRjTtMq1ebLr7BJ4U50lg59RObkC1O1@TCas3xdnuMROuUi984TEH5CUkDneLBzm0@WV5nfurd1PvfeunKOFJW6Otwu7IKOtE2yZGewIbkq3S52pKIq@NOhzxFAlvnJkGiRqYLHm0qD6ioqmdmKuUS7hp9@4WoLXv7mBTsiufuYKNZ4BxMRJGI1M/pVLOukgoXuV0I5HD7qtBD1D7DOHrIpOafHKUdnJwohGojdhztA9YUReQT6SCQtrFJb9LGXrkMLCj1O2cQs/UVkyalK7sJn/07xRVDYKhfVjQuVjEqI3jk5QDyjBuKbSGh8qXhroXg28WiAexIQclDidDTkUrDF4vbA4ISGdtkNgJ7iWeLPNAktnZlP4UzIUnuzIHnRXHypRAzdP3@oYRu5wSCA0ApSve1nC3@Y7wkNu8RCFQOqiqtDJ8mXZY1wLxZntbVcZF0rb6s45GDSyuqJwG6LXvOq47jkIoams123udRJqsl7DMoTGPUMmLhq0QAvoHnQ23Lrq0Ma/Vtk2GVxQJAExTYPqrjjbuWINer5CKpLZxD6XAEhouOXSx7mJAdOggZUqV3anOQu9g0ENStXUEL@qeOFnAGa1gRMAzoUcCmaiMPSvppOGq6BXCZAhi0oHMIZPbS6UzipIH4@KZctV3ZncecQqlycO45MmdEXgR@AjuXGP7V4SWH4qLk9uMtG0pz@YrLq1ml8GIdS7IXcffC6vGAv6QqyPMW/nFlAL/ita3NJ2n@6OhNyfDNAfI2THR7DIek6wmK28E@uinQ4JvceJhQo3DMU@OSKwSuit3/TWIP2ZwaLdL9LjbEWOy7xtuWQYQhTcRs6qvH5mOdIwtyU0OItQtMNWmmP4MIADrAl5eAC@Yx2Piji9UznaLx94VQ3roC@e0i2hXtgMwmqgxx22/rj8eML394gLBScl3CTukrElYrstyxJXt9sNCxL46yX6o1X8MRqXKJqvYxz9Fy1fGiGxLx1H/nOdMRLNxsh0M9@Su7ZNjxuuwdBWu4fTDNr8IQ6O@jg4qrMZi2aCLNVLB6O9JVOXBzpIDHmR@Yrsd9AkT6WtbbLZ9kT5IDiSzqm7TZaV87smVPM2iyIKzYUXubEfkhlrGoBotgU3tzfVxL/P02l@yDX4JSF9JUMvHvpmvL//Dw))

Answer (score 0):

We have to count the number of *admissible* words $w$ of length $n\geq0$ over the alphabet $[9]$, meaning that $w$ should not contain two consecutive odd numbers.
Let $a_n$ be the number of such words.

Fix $n\geq2$. An admissible word $w$ of length $n$ either (a) ends with an even digit or (b) with an odd digit. In case (a) this $w$ is generated by appending an even digit to an arbitrary admissible word of length $n-1$. The number of such $w$s is $\>a_{n-1}\cdot4$, because there are $4$ even digits in the alphabet. In case (b) the  $n$th (odd) digit has to be preceded by an even digit. It follows that this $w$ is generated by appending first an even digit to an arbitrary admissible word of length $n-2$, and then an odd digit. The number of such $w$s therefore is $a_{n-2}\cdot4\cdot5$. Together we obtain the recursion
$$a_0=1,\quad a_1=9,\qquad a_n=4a_{n-1}+20 a_{n-2}\quad(n\geq2)\ .$$
The obtained recursion is a [linear difference equation with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation). Standard techniques (called "Master Theorem" by some) allow to obtain a closed formula for the $a_n$.